# in python2 is OK, but in python3 doesn't work

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.4, binaryfiles

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

f = open('dv.bmp', mode='rb')
slika = f.read()
f.closed

pic   = slika[:28]
slika = slika[54:] 
# dimenzije originalnog bitmapa
pic_w = ord(pic[18]) + ord(pic[19])*256
pic_h = ord(pic[22]) + ord(pic[23])*256
print(pic_w, pic_h)
```

why this code doesn't work in python3 (in python2 it works fine) OR
howto read binary file into string type in python3?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? How does it fail?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./open file 2.py", line 14, in <module>
        pic_w = ord(pic[18]) + ord(pic[19])*256
    TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found

Comment: Just remove ord(), it's redundant in this care because python 3 indexes Bytes as integers

Comment: I'd recommend you edit that traceback into the question, and also try to give a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Python 2.x](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), binary mode (e.g. `'rb'`) only affects how Python interprets end-of-line characters:

> On Windows, `'b'` appended to the mode opens the file in binary mode, so
>   there are also modes like `'rb'`, `'wb'`, and `'r+b'`. Python on Windows
>   makes a distinction between text and binary files; the end-of-line
>   characters in text files are automatically altered slightly when data
>   is read or written. This behind-the-scenes modification to file data
>   is fine for ASCII text files, but it’ll corrupt binary data like that
>   in `JPEG` or `EXE` files. Be very careful to use binary mode when reading
>   and writing such files. On Unix, it doesn’t hurt to append a `'b'` to
>   the mode, so you can use it platform-independently for all binary
>   files.

However in [Python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), binary mode also changes the type of the resulting data:

> Normally, files are opened in *text mode*, that means, you read and
>   write strings from and to the file, which are encoded in a specific
>   encoding. If encoding is not specified, the default is platform
>   dependent (see `open()`). `'b'` appended to the mode opens the file in
>   *binary mode*: now the data is read and written in the form of bytes
>   objects. This mode should be used for all files that don’t contain
>   text.

Since the read results in a bytes object, indexing it results in an integer, not a one-character string as in Python 2. Passing that integer to the `ord()` function raises the error mentioned in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355008/in-python2-is-ok-but-in-python3-doesnt-work#comment62225450_37355008).

The solution is just to omit the `ord()` call in Python 3, since the integer you get from indexing the bytes object is the same as what you'd get from calling `ord()` on the string equivalent.